# What are the js files needed to use the materialize select?

Tags: javascript, forms, select, materialize, dropdown

I am calling these files:

```
      './public/js/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js',
      './public/js/vendor/global.js',
      './public/js/vendor/dropdown.js',
      './public/js/vendor/forms.js',
```

But I think something is missing, because the click is not working when I do this:

```
        $('#mappgingPipeline .select').find('option[value="'+isActive+'"]').prop('selected', true);
        $('#mappgingPipeline .select').material_select();
```

Comment: Any console errors, like `X is not a function`?

Comment: No... but if I put: <script src="http://materializecss.com/bin/materialize.js"></script>, works...